# Android data recovery app

Tags: data-recovery

I need to recover some tar.gz files (compressed) and some txt files (text).

Any app that does that is enough.

Optionally, but important, it should work **within** Android, not with a PC

Thank you ahead

Comment: [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. And [see here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe#group_872) for a selection of data recovery apps (link goes to my website).

Comment: Understand "best app" as "any app". If you analised my request you'd find that what I asked is specific enough to eliminate 99% of the apps out there